# Database Connection Error with ef-code-first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm new to ef code first and have just used the reverse engineer code first to create a model of an existing database on Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

The problem I'm having is that even though I'm providing User ID and Password in the connection string, it's giving me an authentication error while complaining about my computer name as if I were using Integrated Security (which I'm not.)

The error I get is this:

Cannot open database \"edmTestDBContext\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'jwelty-thinkpad\jwelty'.

My connectionString is this:

Data Source=srv-123;Initial Catalog=edmTestDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=userpass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True

It seams to me like it's ignoring my User ID and using my machine name instead.

It's interesting that the connection string was auto generated by the Entity Framework tool and it worked for building the model but not for actually connecting the model back to the source database.

Any thoughts on what's going on?

I do have full permissions with my username/password as this is what I use with Sql Server Management Studio and that's also how I created the database in the first place.

I tried adding "Integrated Security=False;" and that was no help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like EF isn't finding your connection string. Make sure that it is in the config file being used (you might need to copy it from the class library config to the application config) and that it either has the same name as the context class or that you provide DbContext with the name by calling the appropriate base constructor. For example:

```
public EdmTestDBContext()
 : base("name=MyConnectionStringName")
{
}
```

Comment: Right, I have that but had to take out "name=" as I'm using ef 4.3.1 which doesn't like that.

    public class edmTestDBContext : DbContext
    {
        static edmTestDBContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<edmTestDBContext>(null);
        }

  public edmTestDBContext()
   : base("edmTestDBContext")
  {
  }

Comment: If 4.3.1 "doen't like" name= it means that DbContext can't find the connection string. That hasn't changed at all from CTP4 through EF5 RC. From your other comment it seems DbContext couldn't find the connection string because you needed to copy it to the other config, as suggested. When you use name= DbContext throws to let you know that it couldn't find the connection string instead of creating a connection string by convention.

Comment: Oh ok. I had read that somewhere else and had been thinking it was part of my problem. Thank you for clarifying that to avoid any further confusion. I've only just started on the learning curve and am new to C#, EF, CF, and WPF so I'm digesting a lot all at once here.

Answer (score 0):

There are some built-in conventions in EF Code-first such as using the name of derived context class from DbContext to find the related connection string in the .config file.
So if your context class is named `BlogContext`, it will look for the following connectionString first:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add
      name="BlogContext"
...
```

Comment: As it turns out, I was putting the connectionString in the wrong app.config file. I had one in my context project and in my console project which is where the dbcontext object was being used and so it was using the console app.config file.